# Heine Borel Theorem statement (a)

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I have been following [Prof Winston Ou's course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BGvOgTQUDQ&list=PLun8-Z_lTkC5HAjzXCLEx0gQkJZD4uCtJ&index=7) on analysis on Youtube.

In the lecture on Heine Borel theorem, he mentioned that a set $E$ in $\mathbb R$ is closed and bounded implies that $E$ is a k-cell (hence $E$ is compact).

I don't understand how he came to this conclusion. For instance, I imagine $E$ could be a discrete set (and still being closed and bounded), but it will not be a k-cell. I would be very grateful if anyone could enlighten me.

Comment: Can you point the exact time? Sitting through a lecture to clarify some person's statement is not exactly the ideal way to use one's time.

Comment: My apologies, the statement begins at 15:40 of the video.

Comment: What I'm hearing and reading is: "$E$ bounded implies $E$ is *contained in* some $k$-cell. Then, $E$ is closed subset of a compact set. And so it's compact.".

Comment: You are right. I am sorry I misunderstood him. thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He means $D$ will be *contained* in a $k$-cell, and as $k$-cells are compact and $E$ is still a closed subset of it, it will also be compact.

The boundedness *in Euclidean space/metric* forces the set inside a product of compact intervals..